# Problem with dynamic buttons c# and Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

My program has a button generation button, which generates 5 buttons for me, I also have a string list that calls button, which will store in its 5 positions button 1, button 2, button 3, button 4, button 5, and my generated buttons have events and the idea is that when I press the generated button the label text changes to what the list has, but when I press the generated button it only reloads the page and nothing happens, my generated buttons are removed and the label text never changes Can you help me please, I have tried everything and nothing works.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace pruebastack
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void btngenerar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<string> boton = new List<string>();
            for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
            {
                System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button Button1 = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button();
                Button1.Text = "boton" + i;
                boton[i] = "boton" + i;
                Button1.Click += delegate
                {
                    Label1.Text = boton[i];
                };
                this.Panel1.Controls.Add(Button1);
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: After `btngenerar_Click` returns and the rest of the page lifecycle ends, including writing the response, those new button instances and that `WebForm1` instance will go away. You need to track how many buttons you added because you need to reconstitute them (including event handlers) in a `Page_Init` handler the next time the page is requested. Managing dynamically created controls between page loads is very complicated and understanding the page lifecycle is the only way you're going to be able to do it without making an unmanageable spaghetti-like mess of it.

Comment: madreflection 
Could you explain to me how to do the truth, I don't know, please

Comment: A long-form answer here would still only touch on the basics. You need to do some independant study. Start by reading the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/ms178472(v%3Dvs.100)) and try to find blogs that talk about it, and even old SO questions about the specific events. WebForms is an old technology and whatever's been written about it by now is pretty much all there every will be. You may find a lot of broken links because content has been removed.

Comment: madreflection  I've looked everywhere but I don't know how, I really don't know what to do